# Phase Locked Loop: Help and clarification needed

Tags: audio, signal-processing, modem, data-transfer

I have been looking at implementing my own FSK modem. I have the modulation done and am satisfied that it thus far. I am now stuck on the demodulation of the signal.

I have read that a phase locked loop is one way of demodulating an FSK signal. Obviously, I understand how the signal is encoded, and I know that a PLL uses a reference signal to somehow track the carrier frequency. However, I can't link the two together:

- How/when is the reference signal started (is this not relative to some other reference point?).
- How does it "track" the carrier frequency? From what I understand, it somehow calculates the marks and spaces in the carrier frequency. But how?

If someone can explain this in total lamens terms it would be appreciated. I also appreciate it if someone can point me at any code examples of a working PLL.

My application can modulate binary data and send it across an audio cable. At the other end I'm able to obtain that audio data as an array of bytes. From there, I'm a little stuck.

Comment: This might be better directed at [http://dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: A PLL is overkill unless you don't know the exact frequencies. Since you're generating them, and presumably there is no doppler shift or other source of error, then you can probably use a much simpler demodulation scheme.

Comment: Paul R: Can you recommend another scheme? I Would prefer it if the demodulation at the receiving end didn't need to know the exact frequencies but it's not an absolute requirement.

Comment: Have you heard of Goertzel's Algorithm? Its used when you are trying to distinguish between two or more known frequencies and can be used for FSK demodulation. Here's a [PDF](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse466/12au/calendar/Goertzel-EETimes.pdf) about it (includes code samples).